# How to run Selenium Webdriver with pythonw?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open Firefox browser in a Selenium script via a GUI application in Windows. It worked **just fine** while running with `python.exe runw.py`, but when I run it with `pythonw.exe runw.py`, the browser can't start. Instead, it throws me this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin\runw.py", line 215, in process_instance
    instance.setup()
  File "bin\mixin.py", line 181, in setup
    self.browser = self.get_firefox_browser()
  File "bin\mixin.py", line 166, in get_firefox_browser
    firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=profile)
  File "C:\myvirtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "C:\myvirtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "C:\myvirtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 60, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "C:\myvirtualenv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 83, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env).communicate()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 702, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 833, in _get_handles
    p2cread = self._make_inheritable(p2cread)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 884, in _make_inheritable
    _subprocess.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS)
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

The problem certainly lies on having no `stdin` or `stdout` (I'm not sure), because it fails in this line (`firefox_binary.py`):

```
def _start_from_profile_path(self, path):
    ...
    Popen(command, stdout=self._log_file, stderr=STDOUT,
          env=self._firefox_env).communicate()
    command[1] = '-foreground'
    self.process = Popen(
        command, stdout=self._log_file, stderr=STDOUT,
        env=self._firefox_env)
```

I've tried overriding `syd.stdout` with an output file before running the browser, but it didn't work:

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('log.txt', 'a+')
```

I'm running Python2.7 and Selenium 2.40. How can Selenium run with `pythonw`?

Comment: Have you tried making `STDOUT` reference your new value for sys.stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @falsetru said, `subprocess` is trying to user file descriptor `0`. The subprocess call will **only work** if all handles are valid (or if they are all `None`), and as `pythonw` is a Windows process and doesn't have any, I was forced to subclass `FirefoxBinary` to use `nul` handles:

```py
class WindowsFirefoxBinary(FirefoxBinary):

    def _start_from_profile_path(self, path):
        self._firefox_env["XRE_PROFILE_PATH"] = path

        if platform.system().lower() == 'linux':
            self._modify_link_library_path()
        command = [self._start_cmd, "-silent"]
        if self.command_line is not None:
            for cli in self.command_line:
                command.append(cli)

        # Added stdin argument:
        nul = open(os.devnull, 'w+')
        Popen(command, stdin=nul, stdout=self._log_file or nul, stderr=STDOUT,
              env=self._firefox_env).communicate()
        command[1] = '-foreground'
        self.process = Popen(
            command, stdin=nul, stdout=self._log_file or nul, stderr=STDOUT,
            env=self._firefox_env)
```

This way I can use my own binary when creating the WebDriver instance:

```
binary = WindowsFirefoxBinary()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

This may be a bug or simply incompatibility in Selenium with Python for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `subprocess` try to use stdin (file descriptor `0`, not `sys.stdin`).

Work around: Open a file **for reading** at the beginning of the script (to make file descriptor 0 which will be used by `subprocess` code).

```
import os
open(os.devnull, 'r')
```